# Why `let` isn't specified as reserved keyword in the spec

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was expecting to find both `const` and `let` as reserved keywords. [I've found only](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-ReservedWord) `const`, but there's no `let`:

```
Keyword::
    await
    break
    case catch class const continue   <---- `const` here
    debugger default delete do
    else export extends
    finally for function
    if import in instanceof
    new
    return
    superswitch
    this throw try typeof
    var void
    while with
    yield
```

Is `let` a keyword? And if not, why?

Comment: Look down just a notch and you'll find a note that says "let and static are treated as reserved words through static semantic restrictions (see 12.1.1, 13.3.1.1, 13.7.5.1, and 14.5.1) rather than the lexical grammar."

Comment: There's a note right there explaining the status of `let`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`let` wasn’t reserved before <del>ES6</del> [ES5 strict mode](https://es5.github.io/#C), so it can’t be treated the same as the rest of the reserved words for backwards-compatibility reasons like this:

```
var let = 5;
```

You’ll find lots of exceptions for it in the spec for new constructs (e.g. `let let = 5;` is invalid).

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain the reason for not including it into the keyword productions

Answer (score 1):

You can see the note in the [referenced document](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-ReservedWord):

> In some contexts yield and await are given the semantics of an Identifier. See 12.1.1. In strict mode code, **let** and static are treated as reserved words through static semantic restrictions (see 12.1.1, 13.3.1.1, 13.7.5.1, and 14.5.1) rather than the lexical grammar.