# Why is `const` a reserved keyword in JS but `let` isn't

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Looking at JS Reserved words ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words)), it looks like new features are introduced in backwards-compatible manner, meaning `var let = 0, async = 1, await = 2;` is a valid expression, at least outside `strict` mode. See: [Why are await and async valid variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names/55934491) and [Why `let` isn't specified as reserved keyword in the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754064/why-let-isnt-specified-as-reserved-keyword-in-the-spec)

However, `const` is an actual keyword, so you cannot do `var const = 0;` (see: [this post](https://dev.to/metajunaid/is-let-not-a-reserved-keyword-in-javascript-56bh)).

```
var let = 100; // OK
var const = 100; // SyntaxError: Cannot use the keyword 'const' as a variable name.
```

What bugs me is: why? I assume it means `const` was already reserved years before `let`/`const` came to be, but what meaning did it have back then? Was it just reserved for future intentions?

Comment: When defining a language you define reserved keywords that are used and that might be used in future. And it they thought `const` might be used at some time, maybe because it already existed in other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume it means `const` was already reserved years before `let`/`const` came to be?

Yes. You can find it as a reserved word since ECMAScript 1.

> But what meaning did it have back then? Was it just reserved for future intentions?

Yes:

> ***Future Reserved Words***
> *The following words are used as keywords in proposed extensions and are therefore reserved to allow for the possibility of future adoption
> of those extensions.*
>
> ```
> FutureReservedWord :: one of
> case   debugger  export   super
> catch  default   extends  switch
> class  do        finally  throw
> const  enum      import   try
> ```

Many of these were used in later versions of the language, like `switch`/`case`/`default` in ES3, `try`/`catch`/`finally`/`throw` in ES3, `class`/`extends`/`super` in ES6, `export`/`import` in ES6, `do` (with `while`) in ES3, the `debugger` statement in ES5, and `const` in ES6. `enum` is the only keyword that has been unconditionally reserved for the future in all versions of the language so far.

ECMAScript 2 added even more Java-like reserved keywords, the list from back then:

> ```
> abstract  do import short
> boolean   double      instanceof  static
> byte      enum        int         super
> case      export      interface   switch
> catch     extends     long        synchronized
> char      final       native      throw
> class     finally     package     throws
> const     float       private     transient
> debugger  goto        protected   try
> default   implements  public      volatile
> ```

ES3 implemented a few those.

[ES5](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2) then removed some of the Java-isms like primitive type names and method modifiers, but also introduced some new reserved keywords (`let`, `yield`) and made a distinction in strict mode:

> ```
> FutureReservedWord :: one of
> class  enum    extends  super
> const  export  import
> ```
>
> *The following tokens are also considered to be `FutureReservedWords` when they occur within strict mode code:*
>
> ```
> implements  let      private    public  yield
> interface   package  protected  static
> ```

[ES6](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-future-reserved-words) implemented classes and modules, leaving only `enum`, and introduced `await` as a reserved keyword in modules only. The [rules of reserved keywords](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words) got only more complicated since, so that they are no longer described in the lexical grammar but rather as static semantic restrictions.